# Any sound which is played from Google Chrome is very low pitch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, audio, ubuntu-10.04

Any sound which is played from Google Chrome is very low pitch, doesn't matter which website or source i.e. video from youtube, music from flash games and etc. However if I open same content in other browser i.e. Firefox everything is fine or if I open some mp3 file from my computer via music player everything is fine again. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 if that matters.

Comment: Have you checked the volume mixer? And pitch, or volume?

Comment: This is confusing. Do you actuall mean volume? Pitch is high and low not loud and soft.

Comment: @soandos well I don't know exact term (pitch or volume) but woman voice sounds very ugly like a man. Can't find volume mixer in chrome settings.

Comment: Could be related to this: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1587

Answer (score 3):

Had that issue as well in Linux Mint 15 and it seems the distros share the same Sound Settings gui. Click your volume-icon, select Sound Settings, go to the Applications tab and adjust the volume for Chromium/Chrome.

[image: Linux Mint Sound Settings - Applications Tab]